# Ethereum Bucket Synchronisation

Tags: blockchain, ether, synchronization

The normal operation of Ethereum and other blockchains is to Store new transactions in a mempool, Distribute the bucket, and then mine contents into a block picked from the bucket based on priority of the Gas fee and execution time to fire within the 15 Seconds execution window.
The big Question I am find difficulty answering after long search and much reading is what method does the Chain use to Synchronise those Buckets?
Does anyone have a flow chart, Description or link to an article that explains the mechanism.
Some problems come to mind that I don't have clarity on how its solved, for example. When a node receives a new transaction, what is the logic for it to be transmitted around the network? is it a Pull Push, Transmit or other Synch method, that handles out of sync issues, such as keeping track of what transactions have already been synched to its neighbor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The normal operation of Ethereum and other blockchains is to Store new transactions in a bucket

Ethereum does not store transactions in a bucket and this is not standard terminology.

[The Ethereum transaction life cycle is explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65842575/315168).

Comment: Thanks. that linked me to this article which is exactly what I was looking for. https://medium.com/shyft-network-media/understanding-ethereums-p2p-network-86eeaa3345
Thankyou.